# The Vox Populi badge is multiplying!

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I seem to have earned this new badge several times for my efforts today, and it seems that am now being awarded a new copy once every 5 minutes... I'm thinking that something might be broken:

[image: my user activity showing multiple awards of the Vox Populi badge split over five minute intervals]

Comment: Oh wow, I've just got *another one*... (now edited in to question)

Comment: And there's my fifth! I seem to be getting one every five minutes now... :/

Comment: And there's the sixth, after another five minute gap, so they do seem to be on a regular interval. I'm going to stop updating this question now as I think we can all see the pattern now being formed...

Comment: Are you from Chicago?

Comment: I found the issue and pushing a change right now to stop the dupe assignments, cleanup will be another pass.

Comment: "Vox Populi" is a good name for a virus :)

Comment: I for one am glad that all of my efforts to upvote questions are finally being appreciated by *someone*! ;-)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The dupe assignment of this badge (due to a rename) should be fixed now.  In a moment I'm going to be super mean and TAKE ALL THOSE BADGES AWAY!

However, you'll get one you should have back for today, it'll be reassigned automatically on the next pass.

Comment: Yup, there's the reset. Good stuff, thanks.

Comment: :-( I had six of them I thought I was winning