# Vox populi badge received three times per one day

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The Vox Populi badge is multiplying!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90499/the-vox-populi-badge-is-multiplying)

[I](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217288/yojimbo87) just received Vox populi badge third time during this day. Not sure if trolling or serious.

[image]

Comment: This was already reported at [The Vox Populi badge is multiplying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90499/the-vox-populi-badge-is-multiplying). Hopefully we won't see this question multiply all too much. ♪