# Hey Look! Someone has Vox Populi x 7?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

This is possibly a duplicate of: [The Vox Populi badge is multiplying!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90499/the-vox-populi-badge-is-multiplying)

However, that was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) back in May last year. This one happened in January this year.

[image]
[image]
[image]

The user in question is: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152862/navid-rahmani

Comment: The more recent bug report is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123159/vox-populi-civic-duty-and-electorate-badges-being-awarded-en-masse), although that's also marked [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Cody: That question was about them being awarded en masse to a multitude of users, not the same user multiple times.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean that it was a duplicate. The originally linked question concerned multiple users receiving the badge as well (see comments).

Comment: I think I might know what's going on but I'm asking inside about this one.

Comment: probably a whole bunch of users were merged into one...

Comment: That would be some pretty awesome sockpuppeting if 7 accounts each voted 40 times in one day. lol

Comment: I *suspect* this is connected to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/some-users-are-more-enthusiastic-than-others - but that is pretty crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually an ancient bug that happened because of a long gap in the run of the badge (by random chance) job and the way the query was written.  The query has since been fixed but I just now found time to clean up the duplicates (only on 4 users).

They are now down to 1 Vox Populi badge and their badge counts have been synced up.